# Find arc-length of particle moving on constantly changing radius circle

Tags: differential-geometry, line-integrals, arc-length

I want to create function (integral) of particle moving on changing radius circle in constant speed.
I have the following things I know:

1. angle corresponding to the arc that the particle moved (degrees).
2. starting circle radius and ending circle radius.

I've came to the following double integral:

$\int_{r1}^{r2} (\int_{0}^{\alpha} \frac{d\theta}{360})*2\pi dr $

But this will probably calculate the region that is closed between the original circle (radius $r_1$) arc-length and the changing circle radius arc-length, therefore, I need some line integral but I can't find the line integral integrand function.

I'm adding graphic that will demonstrate my goal:
[image]

Comment: Why should this question be closed ? We must just ask the OP to be clearer 1) about the center of his circular arcs 2) by providing an illustration.

Comment: In particular, if the speed is constant, it means that we can choose a parametric representation with a parameter which is a multiple of the curvilinear abscissa.

Comment: @JeanMarie The center of the circular for both arcs remain the same.
I will provide an illustration.
But basically the second thing you wrote is the formula I'm looking for, How can I create it?

Comment: The fact that the center of curvature remains the same looks to me very difficult to achieve ; I am awaiting your graphics. Besides, there are some curves having a rather simple expression for their curvilinear abscissa $s$ such as the cycloids (see [here](https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/cycloid/cycloid.shtml))

Comment: I've added a graphic that shows what I want to achieve.  
Sorry in advance for the bad painting.

By the way, The link you gave me probably answer my question. Thanks

Comment: "Because the speed is constant I can assume the angle change is very small": what ??

Comment: The question is unclear. Do yo mean that the distance to the origin is increasing at a constant speed *and* the particle is moving at constant speed ? If only one of the speeds is constant, the problem is underspecified I guess.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Ohh. this is left overs I didn't removed when I edited my questions.   
Basically, The particle is moving in constant speed while the "radius" of the circle that it is moving on is constantly changes.  
pencil drawn line in the graphics I've added is what I need to calculate

Comment: You can use the radius of curvature in polar coordinates given [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RadiusofCurvature.html) and try for example an arc of a logarithmic spiral $r=e^{0.1 \theta}$. Are you sure you need a constant speed parameterization ?

Comment: You didn't answer my other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constant squared speed is given in polar coordinates by

$$v^2=r^2\dot\theta^2+\dot r^2.$$

As the radial speed is known to be constant, the angular speed is given by

$$\dot\theta=\frac{\sqrt{v^2-v_r^2}}r=\frac{\sqrt{v^2-v_r^2}}{v_rt+r_0}.$$

By integration

$$\theta-\theta_0=\frac{\sqrt{v^2-v_r^2}}{v_r}\log\left(\frac{v_r}{r_0}t+1\right)=\frac{\sqrt{v^2-v_r^2}}{v_r}\log\left(\frac r{r_0}\right).$$

This is a logarithmic spiral. The arc length is obviously given by $vt$.